# UICollectionViewController seems to only display its CollectionView

Tags: ios6

Why does the UICollectionViewController only seem to allow display of its CollectionView? If I add other components to it they never seem to display. They show up fine in the storyboard, but they're not visible when run in the simulator.

Here's what my storyboard looks like:

[image]

And then when I run it in the simulator, I get a black screen with only the CollectionView visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UICollectionViewController` is a view controller whose *entire* content is a collection view.

To get the behavior you need, instead drag out a generic `UIViewController` and add a `UICollectionView` (not a `UICollectionViewController`) as a subview of the `UIViewController`'s `view`.

Then you can resize the `UICollectionView` to your needs and add the labels as subviews of the `UIViewController`'s `view`.

The view hierarchy in Interface Builder would look similar to this:

[image]